# n.data.map is not a function in React

Tags: reactjs, django

I am getting this error which may indicate the `map` function require arrays, while the data provided is not of the data type required.

The console output in the browser

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: n.data.map is not a function
    t watchlistStore.jsx:14
    d watchlistStore.jsx:2
    O watchlistStore.jsx:2
    E watchlistStore.jsx:2
    em watchlistStore.jsx:2
    a watchlistStore.jsx:2
    promise callback*em watchlistStore.jsx:2
    a watchlistStore.jsx:2
    n watchlistStore.jsx:2
    n watchlistStore.jsx:2
    fetchStocks watchlistStore.jsx:22
    im indexWatchlist.jsx:15
    React 3
    k scheduler.production.min.js:13
    T scheduler.production.min.js:14
    53 scheduler.production.min.js:14
    Webpack 12
```

```
import React from "react";
import { create } from 'zustand';
import axios from 'axios';

const watchlistStore = create((set) => ({
    stocks: [],
    filteredStocks: [],

    fetchStocks: async () => {
        console.log(`Fetching Watchlist`);
        const response = await axios.get('/watchlist');
        if (response.data != 0) {
            const stocks = response.data.map((stock) => {
                return {
                    symbol: stock.symbol,
                    name: stock.name,
                }
            });
            set({ stocks });
        };
    },
}));

export default watchlistStore;
```

The data to be fetched `/watchlist`

```
{'symbol': 'WISH', 'name': 'ContextLogic Inc.'}{'symbol': 'GTII', 'name': 'Global Tech Industries Group, Inc.'}{'symbol': 'CCFN', 'name': 'CCFNB Bancorp, Inc.'}{'symbol': 'GAME', 'name': 'Engine Gaming and Media, Inc.'}{'symbol': 'SEMR', 'name': 'Semrush Holdings, Inc.'}
```

The view in the backend:

```
def watchlist(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        dataList = list()
        for x in Tickers.objects.filter(users=request.user):
            dataList.append({'symbol':x.symbol, 'name':x.name})
        return HttpResponse(dataList)
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Watchlist is empty')
```

Comment: Can you insert console.log('response:' , response) to see what do you get as a response?

Answer (score 3):

Your `response.data` is not automatically an `Array` you can `map()` from! You have to parse accordingly.

```
const stocks = JSON.parse(response.data).map((stock) => {
    return {
        symbol: stock.symbol,
        name: stock.name,
    }
});
```

Comment: Like I mentioned in my other comment; *"use Django’s `JsonResponse` to ensure proper JSON encoding"*.

Answer (score 1):

You return isn't a proper JSON, you need the following fix in your Django View

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

# in your main return 
return JsonResponse(dataList)
```

Comment: It doesn’t matter if it is `HttpResponse` or `JsonResponse` used. HTTP is a text based protocol. The end result is still a sequence of characters. A standard string/text.

Comment: It matters because JSONResponse also set the content-type header so it can be detected by the client, also, it uniform the string and booleans to be confirming with JS. like True in Python is true in JS

Comment: The header: {content-type} is for the client to know what is coming through in HTTP. The OP clearly doesn’t use it. So the OP doesn’t need it.

Comment: *”also, it uniform [? unifies] the string and booleans to be confirming with JS. like `True` in Python is `true` in JS”*. This is indeed true so I will implore the OP to use Django’s `JsonResponse` to ensure proper JSON encoding. One upvote from me.

Answer (score 0):

`response.data` is supposed to be an array after parsing to `JSON`, so your check is incorrect.

```
const response = await axios.get('/watchlist');

try {
  const parsedData = JSON.parse(response.data)
  // very strict check
  if (Array.isArray(parsedData) && parsedData.length > 0) {
    // map over array and call set()
  }

  } catch {
    // console.log for example
  }
```

Comment: `response.data` is not an array. It’s a sequence of characters. A standard string/text. HTTP is a text based protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your endpoint returns a valid json:

```
[
    {
        "symbol": "WISH",
        "name": "ContextLogic Inc."
    },
    {
        "symbol": "GTII",
        "name": "Global Tech Industries Group, Inc."
    },
    {
        "symbol": "CCFN",
        "name": "CCFNB Bancorp, Inc."
    },
    {
        "symbol": "GAME",
        "name": "Engine Gaming and Media, Inc."
    },
    {
        "symbol": "SEMR",
        "name": "Semrush Holdings, Inc."
    }
]
```

Comment: The code returns valid JSON. Django’s `HttpResonse` will turn a `list` to valid JSON.